# Parses input from a string according to a format with Powershell?

Tags: string, parsing, powershell

I'm new to `Powershell` and I wonder if there is any way to parse input from a string according to a format, just like the `sscanf()` function in PHP?

[URL Refered](http://php.net/sscanf)

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such a thing in PowerShell. But for a particular task a solution can be found anyway, otherwise such a thing would exist. For example, regular expressions are often used in PowerShell for simple and effective parsing.

Comment: It's sad to hear so but thanks for the information though. I will use regular expressions instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP `sscanf` can be emulated with matching the input with a regex. As per the PHP manual page example, let's parse author data into XML like so,

```
$auth = "24`tLewis Carroll" # ` is the escape char in PSh
$mc = [regex]::Match($auth, "(\d+)\t(\w+)\s(\w+)")
write-host $("<author id='{0}'>`n  <firstname>{1}</firstname>`n  <surname>{2}</surname>`n</author>" -f $mc.Groups[1].Value, $mc.Groups[2].Value, $mc.Groups[3].Value)
```

Output

```
<author id='24'>
  <firstname>Lewis</firstname>
  <surname>Carroll</surname>
</author>
```